# Filter cells based on multiple data in 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

[image]

Hi,

I need to create a conditional filter where **at least 3** of the numbers in **either** cell is **greater than 60**. I have highlighted the rows in bold that qualify.

The first one (lets call them a1 and b1 ) do not qualify as only 1 number is over 60

The second row (a2 and b2) qualifies as there are 3 numbers in that row over 60, 74,85,80

It does not matter if the numbers of 60 are in a single cell in the row or a mixture of both as shown below

Thank you, I look forward to your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kLTO2aXby3QAgrnJ9muJ7fLJsrmMesM6-TOKaMVbtYg/edit#gid=1712294730)

Conditional Formatting contains following formula

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIF(SPLIT($A1&","&$B1,","),">60")>2,TRUE,FALSE))
```

where *$A1&","&$B1* are first cells of range of your data (can be adjusted).

Comment: Hi Oleg, is it possible to also filter out/remove the data that doesn't fit the criteria

Comment: You can create filter and filter by color. Or see the file, I added quick solution, it uses support sheet, so you can hide it.